# Can I keep worker and GUI separate without cross thread exceptions in mixed Console and WinForms environment?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console-application

I have a project I'm working on that has a Windows gui (optional) and a worker that can either write to the gui or to the console, if no gui is given. The gui is optional to make this project backwards compatible with systems that may not have a desktop environment (I also may end up remaking this project eventually in C or C++ but for time constraints sake I need something to work right now). The majority of the computers the program will run on (for now) have Windows XP. (I am targeting .NET Framework 4.0.3).

Due to the fact that I want the gui to be optional, I don't want the worker class to live inside a `BackgroundWorker` or a `Form`. In my real project I have a `UserInterface` "interface" (c# interface) that can be implemented by a variety of user interfaces.

In the Windows GUI, tfhere is a main `Form` with a button that opens a dialog `Form`. The dialog has a multiline textbox that can have lines appended to it by the worker.

Since I am not using a `BackgroundWorker` or other conventional ways of doing things, I have ran into various problems relating to cross threading operations and calling `BeginInvoke` before a window handle has been created. I was able to "solve" the window handle problem by essentially calling `_ = MainForm.Handle` in `MainForm`'s constructor to force the creation of a window handle creation before the window is shown (so that the worker can append lines to a textbox, which could happen before the gui has been shown).

Here is my minimal, reproducible example that captures the problem I am having in my real project. The problem is encountered when either a) removing creation of window handle from `MainForm` constructor, which causes `BeginInvoke` to complain about being called before the window handle has been created, or b) as it is now, once the dialog window is closed and reopened the call to `ShowDialog` fails due to cross thread operations.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MinimalExample
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Gui gui = new Gui();
            Worker worker = new Worker(gui);

            worker.start();
            gui.show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Gui.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MinimalExample
{
    class Gui
    {
        private readonly DialogForm _dialog_form;
        private readonly MainForm _main_form;

        public Gui()
        {
            _dialog_form = new DialogForm();
            _main_form = new MainForm(_dialog_form);
        }

        public void addLine(string line)
        {
            _dialog_form.addLine(line);
        }

        public void show()
        {
            Application.Run(_main_form);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainForm.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MinimalExample
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private readonly DialogForm _dialog_form;

        public MainForm(DialogForm form)
        {
            _dialog_form = form;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _dialog_form.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**DialogForm.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MinimalExample
{
    public partial class DialogForm : Form
    {
        public DialogForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _ = Handle;
            _ = textBox1.Handle;

            /* Visible = true;
               Visible = false; */
        }

        public void addLine(string line)
        {
            Action action = () =>
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(line);
                textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            };

            if (InvokeRequired)
                textBox1.BeginInvoke(action);
            else
                action();

        }
    }
}
```

**Worker.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace MinimalExample
{
    internal class Worker
    {
        private readonly Gui _gui;
        private readonly Thread _thread;

        internal Worker(Gui gui)
        {
            _gui = gui;
            _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(working));
            _thread.IsBackground = true;
        }

        private void working()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_gui != null)
                    _gui.addLine("Test");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Test");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        public void start()
        {
            _thread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

What is happening here? And, is there a way I can keep the `Gui` and the `Worker` separate yet not have these runtime exceptions?

Comment: In 2020 you don't need `BackgroundWorker` or `Thread` at all. Learn how to use `Task` based classes and async/await, https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-replace-backgroundworker-with-async-await-and-tasks-80d7c8ed89dc then your goals can be easily achieved with clean code.

Comment: I had ran across this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-worth-the-await/ and assumed that async wasn't an option in 4.0.3. Can I still use `Task` without the async keyword?

Comment: Why not make two .EXEs, the **main** one that the user runs that either a) spawns the 2nd .EXE representing the **GUI app** if so required or b) continues to run as a console app.  That way your 2nd EXE GUI app doesn't require any change to threading as you have done.

Comment: I would normally agree, but unfortunately I have to target 4.0.3 because the program I am making will be mostly running on older Windows XP machines and Windows XP only supports up to 4.0.3.

Comment: Well depending on what you are doing you don't need `await` to use `Task`.  e.g. _fire-and-forget tasks_

Comment: If you do use a newer VS release that supports C# 5, then projects targeting .NET Framework 4.0.x can still use async/await, via third party solutions like AsyncBridge, http://omermor.github.io/AsyncBridge/ . Another option is to run .NET Core self-contained apps on Windows XP, which of course is not supported by Microsoft either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Threading part is not an issue here. You just need to handle the Form creation in a slightly different way:

**First setup:**

- The Form's Handle creation can be forced calling [CreateHandle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.createhandle) right after `InitializeComponent()` (the [.Net Source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,3634) related to the method call is more interesting, also note the call to [UpdateHandleWithOwner()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,6427)).
- The next condition to show the output of the worker thread, is that the Form is also Visible, since also the TextBox Handle needs to exist when it's invoked.
- The Gui class needs to `BeginInvoke()` the Form's `AddLine()` method, since the method call is generated in a different thread (the `Gui` object is used by the `Worker` object thread).
- I've added a public property to the Gui class: **`public bool CanWrite`**: the Worker class can inspect this property to determine where it should write its output.
  The public property returns: **`dialogForm != null && dialogForm.Visible;`**, this because ↓:
- DialogForm is shown calling `ShowDialog()`: this implies that when the DialogForm is closed, the Form is not disposed. Also, the object still has a reference in the Gui class. When it's closed, its `Visible` property returns `false`.

**Second setup:**

- Since (based on comments) this Console application should output to the DialogForm Form when a Gui object is created and the Dialog is not necessarily shown immediately, the TextBox Control in DialogForm should cache lines of text posted by the Thread in the Worker class.
  This requires a simple edit: change **`dialogForm != null && dialogForm.IsVisible`** in just  **`dialogForm != null`**, then verify the handle status before `Gui.AddLine()` is called and caching lines of text if the handle is not available at this time.
- The Owner Form, MainForm, instructs DialogForm to recreate its handle when `DialogForm.ShowDialog()` returns. Since `ShowDialog()` is used to show DialogForm, the form is not disposed. Recreating the handle doesn't casuse child controls to lose their content.

Implement both option:

The `IsVisible` property check could become a Property of Gui, something like `bool UpdateOnDialogVisible`, to test on `CanWrite,` so the text will be written to the TextBox depending on the status of this property.

---

<sub>Tested in:</sub>

<sub>- Windows 7 (I don't have a WinXP machine available)</sub>


<sub>-  .Net Framework 4.0</sub>


<sub>-  C# 5</sub>

In Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
    private static Worker worker = null;
    private static Gui gui = null;

    // [...]

    gui = new Gui();
    worker = new Worker(gui);

    worker.start();
    gui.Show();
}
```

In Gui.cs

```
public class Gui
{
    private StringBuilder sb = null;
    // [...]

    public Gui() {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        dialogForm = new DialogForm();
        mainForm = new MainForm(dialogForm);
    }

    public bool CanWrite {
        get { return dialogForm != null }
        // Or, with the condition that the Dialog is already visible:  
        // get { return dialogForm != null && dialogForm.Visible; }
    }

    public void AddLine(string line) {
        sb.AppendLine(line);
        // Safety measure: cache if the handle is not available at this time
        if (this.CanWrite && dialogForm.IsHandleCreated) {
            dialogForm.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {
                dialogForm.AddLine(sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();
            }));
        }
    }
    // [...]
}
```

In Worker.cs:

```
internal class Worker
{
    // [...]
    private void working() {
        while (true) {
            if (gui != null && gui.CanWrite) {
                gui.AddLine("Test");
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("Test");
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    // [...]
}
```

In DialogForm.cs:

```
public partial class DialogForm : Form
{
    private TextBox textBox1;

    public DialogForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CreateHandle();
    }

    public void AddLine(string line) {
        if (this.IsDisposed || !this.IsHandleCreated) return;
        this.textBox1.AppendText(line);
        this.textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }

    public void RecreateWindow() {
        this.CreateHandle();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent() {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

In MainForm.cs:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private Button button1;
    internal readonly DialogForm dialogForm = null;

    public MainForm() : this(null) { }
    public MainForm(DialogForm form) {
        dialogForm = form;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        if (dialogForm != null) dialogForm.ShowDialog(this);
        button1.Enabled = true;
        // As describe in the notes, if a, e.g., UpdateOnDialogVisible () property is 
        // created, call this method when this property is true, to show text on this 
        // Window only when is Visible.
        dialogForm.RecreateWindow();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent() {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

This is how it works:

► **First Option**:

- The Console output is redirected to a Form only when the designated Form is visible at the time the output is generated:

[image: Console and WinForms Threading 1]

► **Second Option**:
The Console output is always directed to a designated Form when the Gui class is created.

- The Form's handle is recreated each time is closed. Since it ShowDialog() is used to show it, the Form is not disposed.
- The TextBox used to display the Console output can also *cache* the output when the Form is closed.
- A StringBuilder object acts as safety secondary cache, in case the Window handle is not created *at the right time* (since method calls are generated in a different thread, a hypothetical racing condition is taken into consideration).

[image: Console and WinForms Threading 2]

Comment: Alas, it works! Thank you for the explanation of what was happening, I have a better understanding. Just one thing- this program is launched with an option to start a GUI or to not start a GUI, and that is for the lifetime of the program, not a tradeoff depending on whether or not the dialog window is open. If it is launched with a GUI, I don't want a single "Test" to not make it to the dialog window (in reality it's not "Test" being appended to the TextBox, it is lines from a log file). That is why I wanted the dialog to be persistent; I need to be able to modify its contents while not shown.

Comment: I even went so far as to start experimenting with a `ConcurrentQueue<string>` which the worker thread could add the lines to and the dialog could take lines out when being loaded, but that seems so... dumb... Is there absolutely no way to modify a Control while it's not Visible?

Comment: See the edit: I changed Gui's `CanWrite` property to only check for the Handle creation.  Now, if you create Gui, then Worker will test `gui.CanWrite`. Since you created a Gui object, it's already created DialogForm, which already created its Handle. The TextBox Control, even if not visible, will cache the lines value you set. If Gui is not created, the Worker will find it `null` and will write to the Console. You have to make all the changes shown here for it to work.

Comment: I applied your edit suggestions. But on my computer, every time the dialog form is closed, its window handle seems to be destroyed since `CanWrite` will be false when the dialog window is closed, and `if (this.IsDisposed || !this.IsHandleCreated) return;` would also discard any line that would make it there, while when I have it open the lines are appended as expected.

Comment: In other words, `IsHandleCreated` returns false when the dialog window is closed, and when it's shown again `IsHandleCreated` returns true. So if I force it to append lines while `IsHandleCreated` returns false, I get "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created." So it seems to me like I am not able to cache line values.

Comment: I get all lines discarded while the dialog window is closed if I change the condition check in DialogForm.AddLine to `if (this.IsDisposed || !this.IsHandleCreated) { Console.WriteLine("Line was thrown away:" + line); return; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212359/discussion-between-dustin-nieffenegger-and-jimi).