# How can you interact forms in C # VisualStudio WindowsForm with the console?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, cmd

How can you interact forms in C # VisualStudio WindowsForm with the console?
That is, for example, I want to click on the button1 button, with this action, so that a certain text is entered into the console. Or specify the time in the form, and it was entered into the console.
But I have no idea where to start. Thank you for your responses!

Comment: See the two example in: [Can I keep worker and GUI separate without cross thread exceptions in mixed Console and WinForms environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61386769/7444103)

Comment: @Анатолий Бузов, is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps to interact forms with the console.

First, please add a project called Widows Forms Class Library(.NET Framework) in your visual studio 2019.

[image]

Second, please add a form to the library.(I add a button, textbox anddateTimePicker)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            Console.WriteLine(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Third, we can add the library as the reference to the .net framework console app.

Finally, we could use the following code to show the information in the console by clicking the button in the winform.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WinformDll;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello,world");

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]